# NUXTでのKEY情報の隠蔽について

Tags: vue.js, security, nuxt.js

NUXTからAPIを叩く際にKey設定をうまく設定しないと漏洩すると複数のところでみるので、自分の手元でも本当にそうなるのか確認したいのですが、場所がよくわかりらず。。。

具体的にどの場所に書かれているのかご教授頂けますと幸いです。

例えば、こちらのブラウザーから確認できるという表現や

[NuxtJSでgenerate時のみmicroCMSのAPIキーを隠す - Qiita](https://qiita.com/resistance_gowy/items/3cc57f90d8b480b529a5)

こちらの一番下に書かれているネットワークから確認できるという記載の内容などです。

[Nuxt.jsにおけるenvファイルの利用(初学者向けハンズオン) - Qiita](https://qiita.com/fj_yohei/items/c77bff6f0177b4ff219e)

Answer (score 1):

`nuxt build` を実行した時に、 `.nuxt/dist/client` が作成されると思っていますが、もし api キーなどが client に漏れていれば、そこで grep かければ多分見つかると思います。

client 側の js を webpack でビルドしたものが、このディレクトリの中身である、という自分の理解です。(100%の自信がある訳ではないです。多分、ぐらいの感じです)